# How to view an XML document in the Visual Studio browser

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I have an XML file that I want to view in Visual Studio 2012. I am using VB.Net, and when I tried opening it with FileOpen() like I would any other file, it opened in the raw XML with all of the tags. I want it to open as if I just opened it with my default browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a desktop application or ASP.NET?

Comment: I am using VB.Net tot develop a Visual Studio add-in. The end goal is to have the add-in open an xml file generated by a program after the program finishes running.

Comment: If you want it to display as other than raw XML, you'll need to open and parse it using the DOM, and put the XML into something to display it (like a TreeView). (Also, Visual Studio is the development environment, and I'm presuming that it's your **application** that you want to display the XML in, right?)

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but I was able to find a solution. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some more more Googling I was able to find what I was looking for.

http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008012.aspx

The code in the Initialize() method was what I wanted.